# Why is SciPy's ODE Solver Not Producing Correct Solutions?

Tags: python

I am using scipy's ode solver to compute the trajectory of an electron in a B and E field (However currently the E field is zero for all components). I first used very simple numbers for the constants and fields ie. q=m=Bz=Ez=vy=1 and got solutions that were correct. However, when I tried to input more realistic values for q and m, the solutions it gave me were completely incorrect. I don't think it is the ode solvers fault but my own here so I wanted to ask if someone could see what may be wrong with my initial conditions and time steps to see why this is happening. Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import random
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

P0 = [0,0,0]
V0 = [1.759E+11,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,9E-8,num=10E-8)

#Physical/Natural Constants
q_e = -1.602E-19
m_e = 9.11E-31

#Math
ICs = np.concatenate((P0,V0),axis=0)

def BField(x,y,z):

    Bx = 0
    By = 0
    Bz = 1

    BVec = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])

    return BVec

Bout = BField(0,0,0.02)


def EField(x,y,z):

    Ex = 0
    Ey = 0
    Ez = 0
    EVec = np.array([Ex,Ey,Ez])

    return EVec


def LorentzForce(PosVel,t,Constants):

    x,y,z,vx,vy,vz = PosVel
    Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,q_e,m_e = Constants

    EFInput = np.array([Ex,Ey,Ez])
    BFInput = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])
    VelInput = np.array([vx,vy,vz])

    Accel = (q_e/m_e) * (EFInput + np.cross(VelInput, BFInput))   

    LFEqs = np.concatenate((VelInput, Accel), axis = 0)


    return LFEqs


Ex,Ey,Ez = EField(P0[0],P0[1],P0[2])
Bx,By,Bz = BField(P0[0],P0[1],P0[2])
#Ex = Ey = Ez = 0
AllConstantInputs = [Ex,Ey,Ez,Bx,By,Bz,q_e,m_e]
ParticleTrajectory = odeint(LorentzForce, ICs, t, args=(AllConstantInputs,))

print(ParticleTrajectory)


fig = pylab.figure()
particleplot = p3.Axes3D(fig)
plt.plot(ParticleTrajectory[:, 0],ParticleTrajectory[:, 1],ParticleTrajectory[:, 2],'b')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: In your field function definitions no matter what you input as x,y and z, the result will be always the same, because you don't assign anything to them.

Comment: If you mean I assign zeroes to all components no matter the input, then yes I did that on purpose. Otherwise I have misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: When you say ```Bout = BField(0,0,0.02)```, the third component will be 1 still, because your output doesn't depend on inputs. If you did that on purpose, what's the point of defining a function ?

Comment: It is because this is a setup structure to a more complicated problem I wish to solve and so I first want to make sure the ODE solver is producing the correct solution given constant fields. Then once I see it is correct, move on to non-uniform fields.

Comment: At least you should change ```def BField(x,y,z):``` to ```def BField(BX,By,Bz):``` in order to work as you intended. Same to EField.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at [this](https://flothesof.github.io/charged-particle-trajectories-E-and-B-fields.html) article.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at it!